# Rewrite rule in htaccess - Inner pages of my website not loading however home is loading correctly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

askpapa.in/askpapaFinal is opening fine.

[See the problem here](http://askpapa.in/askpapaFinal/categories/index/Govt.%20Service)

root htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /askpapaFinal/
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

App Folder Htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /askpapaFinal/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

webroot htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /askpapaFinal/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where is the rewrite rule for that page? I don't see it.

Comment: Show us your 3 `.htaccess` files, there is one in your root folder, one in the `app` folder and one in the `app/webroot` folder.

Comment: Edited the question. now containing 3 files

Comment: @Holt any clue on this?

Comment: @DushyantKhurana Your `.htaccess` files seem correct, try removing the last `/` in `/askpapaFinal/` but I am not sure it matters that much. Are you sure `mod_rewrite` is enable on your server?

Comment: `<title>IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title>` - so, you're using apache are you? Irrespective or you app setup `app/webroot` should be the document root - _don't_ use a development install in production.